# How to set name of file downloaded from browser?

Tags: html, download

I'm writing a web application that, among other things, allows users to upload files to my server. In order to prevent name clashes and to organize the files, I rename them once they are put on my server. By keeping track of the original file name I can communicate with the file's owner without them ever knowing I changed the file name on the back end. That is, until they go do download the file. In that case they're prompted to download a file with a unfamiliar name.

My question is, is there any way to specify the name of a file to be downloaded using just HTML? So a user uploads a file named 'abc.txt' and I rename it to 'xyz.txt', but when they download it I want the browser to save the file as 'abc.txt' by default. If this isn't possible with just HTML, is there any way to do it?

Comment: `download` attributes it not works for blob url. refer to [How to set the download file extension for blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71686536/6521116)

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Can't find a way in HTML. I think you'll need a server-side script which will output a content-disposition header. In php this is done like this:

```
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="downloaded.pdf"');
```

if you wish to provide a default filename, but not automatic download, this seems to work.

```
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filetodownload.jpg"');
```

In fact, it is the server that is directly serving your files, so you have no way to interact with it from HTML, as HTML is not involved at all.

Comment: Thanks for that. I figured that was the case, just wanted to make absolutely sure.

Comment: You've deleted the question you are linking. Did you resolve it?

Answer (score 142):

When they click a button to download the file, you can add the [HTML5 attribute `download`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download) where you can set the default filename.

That's what I did, when I created a xlsx file and the browser want to save it as zip file.

```
<a href="path/to/file" download="renamed.txt">Download</a>
<a href="downloads/export.xlsx" download="Data-Export.xlsx">Download Export</a>
```

Note that the 'download' attribute only works for [same origin urls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a).

Comment: sometimes download="myfilename" won't work if the filesize is not readable or the myfilename is omitted.

Comment: it depends on if the filesize is readable? i didn't know... but i think i remember i had problems with some files which didnt want to be renamed... maybe that could be the problem... well... in my case the files come from rackspace, so i can't access to the header :D

Comment: There are several ways to avoid that, you can always download the file using curl or wget to a server, rename it using rename(thefileIdownloaded.file myfile.file) and then output the link, set the timer for 10minutes to delete that file and you always have a clean server and the file is on your server in that case you can do anything with it

Comment: "download" attribute is only honored for links to resources with the same-origin.

Comment: `download` attributes it not works for blob url. refer to [How to set the download file extension for blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71686536/6521116)

Answer (score 7):

## just need to use HTML5 `a` tag `download` attribute

### `codepen` live demo

https://codepen.io/xgqfrms/full/GyEGzG/

> my screen shortcut.

[image]

[image]

### update answer

1. whether a file is downloadable depends on the server's response config, such as `Content-Type`, `Content-Disposition`;
2. download file's `extensions` are optional, depending on the server's config, too.

```
'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream',
// it means unknown binary file,
// browsers usually don't execute it, or even ask if it should be executed.

'Content-Disposition': `attachment; filename=server_filename.filetype`,
// if the header specifies a filename,
// it takes priority over a filename specified in the download attribute.
```

### download `blob` url file

```js
    function generatorBlobVideo(url, type, dom, link) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('GET', url);
      xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
      xhr.onload = function(res) {
        // console.log('res =', res);
        var blob = new Blob(
          [xhr.response],
          {'type' : type},
        );
        // create blob url
        var urlBlob = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        dom.src = urlBlob;
        // download file using `a` tag
        link.href = urlBlob;
      };
      xhr.send();
    }

    (function() {
      var type = 'image/png';
      var url = 'https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/logo/icon.png';
      var dom = document.querySelector('#img');
      var link = document.querySelector('#img-link');
      generatorBlobVideo(url, type, dom, link);
    })();
```

https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/HTML5/Blob/index.html

### refs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#download

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types#important_mime_types_for_web_developers

Comment: This doesn't work, at least on chrome. It just says "failed - no file" or "failed - server problem" when I tried it.

Comment: @BrettWoodward Can you show me what's your Chrome Version? It's OK for me. please, see the `gif` demo.

Comment: @BrettWoodward this happens when href value points to page with error. Try removing "download" attribute to check if page works without downloading.

Comment: `download` attributes it not works for blob url. refer to [How to set the download file extension for blob data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71686536/6521116)

Comment: It works for the `blob` url, please see the online live demo https://cdn.xgqfrms.xyz/HTML5/Blob/index.html

Answer (score 4):

Same code as @Hillkim Henry but with **a.remove()** improvement

This forces the document to remove the **a** tag from the body and avoid multiple elements

```js
 const coverntFiletoBlobAndDownload = async (file, name) => {
  const blob = await fetch(file).then(r => r.blob())
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.style.display = 'none'
  a.href = url
  a.download = name // add custom extension here
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
  // Remove "a" tag from the body
  a.remove()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes @Mephiztopheles answer won't work on blob storages and some browsers.

For this you need to use a custom function to convert the file to blob and download it

```js
const coverntFiletoBlobAndDownload = async (file, name) => {
  const blob = await fetch(file).then(r => r.blob())
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
  const a = document.createElement('a')
  a.style.display = 'none'
  a.href = url
  a.download = name // add custom extension here
  document.body.appendChild(a)
  a.click()
  window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url)
}
```

Comment: Works for me. Fast solution. Thank you :)

Answer (score -2):

Well, @Palantir's answer is, for me, **the most correct way**!

If you plan to use that with multiple files, then i suggest you to use (or make one) PHP Download Manager.

**BUT**, if you want to make that to one or two files, **I will suggest you the mod_rewrite option**:

You have to create or edit your **.htaccess** file on *htdocs* folder and add this:

```
RewriteEngine  on 
RewriteRule ^abc\.txt$  xyz.txt
```

With this code, users will download **xyz.txt** data with the name **abc.txt**

NOTE: Verify if you have already the "*RewriteEngine on* " on your file, if yes, add only the **second** for each file you wish to redirect.

**Good Luck** ;)
*(Sorry for my english)*

Comment: Well, @Mephiztopheles's answer is, for me, **the most correct way!**