# How to give exported file name in safari browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

Exported html table to xls file but the name of file is Unknown file.How to customize the name of exported file.

Comment: Do not ask questions without posting the code you have tried

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set name of file downloaded from browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102226/how-to-set-name-of-file-downloaded-from-browser)

Answer (score 0):

You set the `filename` header in the response that performs the download of said file:

`filename="downloaded.xls"`

See, [How to set name of file downloaded from browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102226/how-to-set-name-of-file-downloaded-from-browser)