# HTML5 Video Tag Download As Name

Tags: html, google-chrome, html5-video, data-uri

I am using an html5 `video` tag where the `src` is a data uri:

```
<video controls>
   <source type="video/mp4" src="data:video/mp4;base64,{data} />
<video>
```

which Chrome renders with controls:
[image: controls]
However if I click the download button on the right, the file downloads as `download.mp4`. Is there anyway to control that filename?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283956/is-there-any-way-to-specify-a-suggested-filename-when-using-data-uri may be useful. You'd have to roll your own download button using the `<a>` tag, which has a `download` attribute.

Comment: You can do it server-side: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102226/how-to-set-name-of-file-downloaded-from-browser

Answer (score -3):

In the src attribute just type the name that you want to display while downloading the video. The same name will be displayed while downloading.

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
<source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video
```

In this example, the name of the file to be downloaded will be movie.mp4

Comment: the OP uses inline file as a video so he cannot set the name in the src attribute