# Google Drive API how to vb.net File Download

Tags: vb.net, google-drive-api

My problem is having the File Download with Visual Basic .NET using the Google Drive API. When I use FileStream, it creates the file but does not download it fully. It looks 0MB. I want to make download using FileID. Not by URL.

Where is my code error?

```
Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
If Service.ApplicationName <> "vbNETDriveTools" Then CreateService()
Dim Downloader = New MediaDownloader(Service)
Downloader.ChunkSize = 256 * 1024
Dim fileid1 = "DriveFileID"
Dim Request1 = Service.Files.Get(fileid1)
Dim Results = Request1.Execute()
Dim filename = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\" & Results.OriginalFilename
Using Stream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    Dim Progress = Downloader.DownloadAsync("which url should I write", Stream)
    Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
    Do While Progress.Status = TaskStatus.Running
    Loop
    If Progress.Status = TaskStatus.RanToCompletion Then
        MsgBox("Download Complete!")
    Else
        MsgBox("Download Failed :(")
    End If
End Using
Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

Are there sample codes that you can help as a Windows Form application?

Answer (score 0):

The method `Downloader.DownloadAsync()` requires the usage of an URL instead of the file ID. Check the following information about how to obtain an URL from the fileID for a file on Google Drive.

1. An answer to a similar question on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43557183/11599789) recommends to create the export link as: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/fileIdxxxxx/export&mimeType=xxxxx/xxxxx. Make sure you URL encode the mime type.
2. The Google Drive Api documentation describes the properties `webContentLink` and [`exportLinks`](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files), which you can obtain by listing the files and specifying those properties in the parameter fields.
3. Apps Script features the method [`getDownloadUrl()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#getdownloadurl).

You have to test which of those Links will work for your application.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, but I don't want to download it by URL

Comment: Then unfortunately you cannot use the function  DownloadAsync(), since it requires an URL as parameter: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Download_1_1MediaDownloader

Comment: DownloadAsync () is downloading the first 10MB of my file. What can I use instead?

Comment: Problem with chunksize is the default value of 10MB. What do I need to download this value GB file?

Comment: Have a look if you find useful information in the references: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/reference/1.9.1/classGoogle_1_1Apis_1_1Download_1_1MediaDownloader#a641b76c0708d3b27794dc859bc14c3f1

Comment: Thank you. I solved the problem using Google Drive API v3.

Answer (score 0):

I don't want to download it by URL. I already find the file with FileID and make the download process. The following code allows me to download only 10MB of files to my desktop(http://prntscr.com/ocpd7x). The same file Google Drive is 350MB. How do I download the entire file? Where is the error in the code?

```
If Service.ApplicationName <> "vbNETDriveTools" Then CreateService()
Dim fileid As String = "1PVsSbS5qEhuMEtDPeuPsvA_eBDy_XX_C"
Dim Request = Service.Files.Get(fileid)
Dim Results = Request.Execute()
Dim Downloader = New MediaDownloader(Service)
Dim filename = "C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\" & Results.OriginalFilename
Dim Stream As System.IO.FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
AddHandler Request.MediaDownloader.ProgressChanged, AddressOf ProgChanged
Request.DownloadAsync(Stream)
```